# iOS: UIScrollView leaving space on bottom, How can I have space on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize, intrinsic-content-size

I have scrollView in which subview are getting added from bottom, like adding bricks in wall (in my case only one brick), then next brick on top of that, like that so on. As with default `UIScrollView ContentSize`, Scrolling will happen on top. How can I make scrolling to bottom. If I scroll down I should be able to see other bricks which are added one above the other.

As you can see in below screen shots, start button should go down instead of of up.

Any kind of help be very appreciated.

Thanks

Sample Code:

```
CGFloat initialYPoint = 30;
for (OUSTLevel* currentLevel in self.course.sortedLevelsList) {

    NSArray* nibList = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell* playLevelCell = nil;

    for (UIView* childView in nibList) {
        if ([childView isKindOfClass:[OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell class]]) {
            playLevelCell = (OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell*)childView;
            break;
        }
    }

    CGFloat cellHeight = CGRectGetHeight(playLevelCell.frame);
    CGFloat yPoint = CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollview.frame) - (cellHeight + initialYPoint);
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, yPoint, viewWidth, cellHeight);

    [playLevelCell setFrame:cellFrame];      
    [self.scrollview addSubview:playLevelCell];

    initialYPoint += cellHeight;

    if (!landingNodeLevelData.locked) {
        [playLevelCell.unlockedView setHidden:NO];
        [playLevelCell.lockedView setHidden:YES];

        // Frame calculation for placing pin
        CGFloat centerPoint = playLevelCell.unlockedView.frame.size.width / 4;
        pinXPoint = centerPoint + 5;
        pinYPoint = yPoint - 30;
    }
}

CGRect pinFrame = CGRectMake(pinXPoint, pinYPoint, 80, 80);

[self.pinImageView setFrame:pinFrame];
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.pinImageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pinImageView];
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, initialYPoint);
self.scrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0);
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollview.contentSize.height - self.scrollview.bounds.size.height+ 30);
```

Edit: I am not using constraint layout, I am calculating & setting frame.

[image: First screen]

[image: Second screen]

[image: Third Screen]

[image]

Comment: Are you using constraints to set the `.contentSize` of your scroll view, or calculating the dimensions? How are you adding the "bricks"? Do you need to "see" a new brick added (that is, have the others slide down as the new one appears at the top)?

Comment: No I am not using Constraints, I am calculating Frame then adding as subview. Yes I want to see the brick 0 to be going down and brick 1 and so on,

Comment: Are the "bricks" being added while the app is being used? So you begin with just the Start button... tap it and brick #1 is added... do something and brick #2 is added... and so on? Or are all the bricks inside the scroll view to begin with? And --- any reason you don't want to use a TableView or CollectionView, and just insert a row each time you add a brick?

Comment: No, All bricks will be added in one shot. 

Yes there is good reason for not using TableView or Collection view, because, Cell in them is reusable, and in My case there is a pointer which is always pointing atleast on brick.

Check last screen shot, on brick 1 there is pointer, and this pointer is animatable, from bricks to bricks.

I guess pointer animation is not possible if we use table view or collection view.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to calculate the content Size and Offsets to position your elements correctly. Do you have a small sample of code that you are using?

Comment: Here is sample code, 

https://pastebin.com/VZwbmkNM

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could make things a bit easier on yourself.

If you *Reverse* the order of your "brick" stacking, you can be filling the view from the Top-Down instead of Bottom-Up ... which is much more logical and easier to think about.

This is a modification to your pastebin code. It *should* work fine... I didn't have your data / classes / xib views / etc, but I'm pretty sure I simulated it so this will run without error:

```
// start with 30-pt "padding" at the top
CGFloat initialYPoint = 30;

// reverse the array of OUSTLevel objects so we're going from top-down instead of bottom-up
NSArray *reversed = [[self.course.sortedLevelsList reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

for (OUSTLevel* currentLevel in reversed) {

    NSArray* nibList = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell* playLevelCell = nil;

    for (UIView* childView in nibList) {
        if ([childView isKindOfClass:[OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell class]]) {
            playLevelCell = (OUSTLearningMapPlayLevelCell*)childView;
            break;
        }
    }

    CGFloat cellHeight = CGRectGetHeight(playLevelCell.frame);

    // we're going top-down now, so Y coordinate will be a simple increment
    CGFloat yPoint = initialYPoint;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, yPoint, viewWidth, cellHeight);

    [playLevelCell setFrame:cellFrame];

    [self.scrollview addSubview:playLevelCell];

    initialYPoint += cellHeight;

    if (!landingNodeLevelData.locked) {
        [playLevelCell.unlockedView setHidden:NO];
        [playLevelCell.lockedView setHidden:YES];

        // Frame calculation for placing pin
        CGFloat centerPoint = playLevelCell.unlockedView.frame.size.width / 4;
        pinXPoint = centerPoint + 5;
        pinYPoint = yPoint - 30;
    }
}

CGRect pinFrame = CGRectMake(pinXPoint, pinYPoint, 80, 80);

[self.pinImageView setFrame:pinFrame];
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.pinImageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pinImageView];

// add 30-pt "padding" at the bottom
initialYPoint += 30;

// set contentSize
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, initialYPoint);

// we want to initially see the "Start Rocket" visible at the bottom of the scroll view
CGFloat yOffset = scrollview.contentSize.height - scrollview.bounds.size.height;
scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, yOffset);
```

Hope it helps - if anything's not clear, ask away :)